# .htaccess - исключение определенных типов(расширений) файлов. Как реализовать?

Tags: .htaccess

На сайте генерируется sitemap по такому принципу: `/public/{название хоста}/sitemap.xml`. Размещается не в корне `public`, так как админка опционально дает возможность настраивать мультисайт и для каждого host нужна своя карта сайта.

Вопрос в следующем, при таком `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Получается следующее. Например сгенерированная карта-сайта для `site-1` доступна по двум URL:

1. http://example.com/site-1/sitemap.xml
2. http://example.com/sitemap.xml

Выяснил, что такое поведение происходит из-за `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]` (если закомментировать данное правило 2. перестает работать). Но как не сложно догадаться - его убирать нельзя :)

Соответственно, возможно ли скорректировать `.htaccess` так, чтобы правило: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]` не учитывало расширение `*.xml`

В такого рода настройках - опыта не много (точнее его почти нет :) ), поэтому решил попросить помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрев схожие темы нашел решение, в `.htaccess` добавить следующее условие:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[^/\.]*\.xml$
```